# Top navigation bar items not responding well

Tags: css

When hovering over the top nav bar items the selection turns on and off when you hover over certain areas within the item, making it difficult to select them. one of the items contains a drop down menu and it's tricky to find the right spot that will open it.

The site is http://cliponexpress.com

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "not responding well"...kind vague don't you think? Please post a reduced example in Jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Comment: The problem is actually the element with id logo2 that has the paypal link inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Remove style "margin-left:1500%" from your "paypal.png" image.

Step2: Append style="right:0; position:absolute;" to  tag for payment.

Step3: Move your Secure payment link along with image (That is overlapping your menu list indexes). to the div with classname "menusys_multi".

Finally Your code will look somewhat like below

```
<div class="menusys_multi">

    <ul id="menusys_multi">....</ul> <!---Unaltered-->
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>  <!---Unaltered-->

    <a onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/p…, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, height=100'); return false;" title="How PayPal Works" href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" style="right:0; position:absolute">
        <img border="0" alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark" z-index="10000" src="http://cliponexpress.com/test/Newwebsite/images/Paypal.png" style="width:18vw;"></img>
    </a>

</div>
```